# Creating a sidebar - Scrollbar display issue - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, resize, scrollbar, sidebar

Ok, I looked everywhere and couldn't find a working solution for the following issue:

I create a simple sidebar in html using css, which is larger than the browser-window, so scrollbar is displayed:

```css
  #sidebar 
     {
  display: table;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: none;
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #757575;   
     }
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>   <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
 
     </div>
```

If scrollbar does not appear, just add a couple more lines.

Now my issue is, when the scrollbar appears it always appears at the right side of the browser instead of directly at the sidebar.

I found a lot of possible solutions, which I tried, like:
 - setting overflow-y to every value possible
 - changing the "display" parameter to every value possible (including flex, inherit, inline-table)
 - setting a max-width

it appears like the system always assumes the sidebar to strech over the whole screen, because when using the display:inherit value it does exactly that

Also I couldn't figure out how to make the sidebar resizable, so the user can change the width like with a normal window, I assume these issues are connected.

Do you have ideas I haven't tried yet? I know one solution would be using frames, but also heard those are rarely used anymore and when trying that there were other issues occuring

Comment: Could you compress this to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

First you can't use li tag without wrapping it into ul tag.

For example:

```
<ul>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

Reference :https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp

I guess you want to achieve something like this. Refer below code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        Give this area width as 70% using css
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        Give this area width as 30% using css
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes adding new top-level containers to arrange your child elements shoudl do the trick.

Comment: @Berlin_Bro Exactly. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh, well, in the real code I used <ul>, this was just an example which produced the same issue as the real code.

But I finally found a way to have the scrollbar at the correct place. Those 2 div classes I already used, but the strange thing was that the scrollbar was not placed at the sidebar, but at the right side of the main area. Still do not understand why, to be honest. Maybe using table-cells it creates it at the right end of the table or something o.O

Comment: Oh I should add: The solution I found was to use flex display for sidebar instead of tables or table cells, this makes some other issues but I guess its the lesser of two evils ;)